# Wait for an input BATCH

Tags: batch-file, input, wait

What i want is a bat file to wait for an input for certain amount of time. If there is no input i want it to GOTO somethingidk.

Here is what i have so far.

```
@echo off
:START
cls
timeout 10
set input=
set /p input= Amount of RAM: 
if '%input%' == '%input%' GOTO CRAFTBUKKIT
:FALLBACK
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4G -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit.jar"
:CRAFTBUKKIT
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx%input%G -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit.jar"
goto START
```

Comment: `if '%input%' == '%input%'` This always will be the case !!! What should the value of `%input%`be ? and when should it go to `:fallback`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `choice` command with `/t`:

```
@echo off
:START
cls
set errorlevel=0
Choice /m "Message: " /t 10
if '%errorlevel%'=='%0%' GOTO CRAFTBUKKIT
:FALLBACK
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4G -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit.jar"
:CRAFTBUKKIT
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx%input%G -jar "%~dp0craftbukkit.jar"
goto START
```

Type `choice /?` in cmd to learn more.